# Here maps Android SDK crash when setting MapMarker icon with setBitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, here-api

Using the Here maps Android starter sdk, I need to rotate a MapMarker in real time to mirror the rotation (yaw) of a real drone. Because the Here maps Android sdk doesn't appear to have a way to set the rotation for a marker (setRotation with google maps), I rotate the marker's icon with my own code then call setIcon() on the marker with a new Bitmap everytime it needs to be updated. However it seems to randomly cause this crash in the Here drawing code, is there any way to prevent this crash from happening?

```
E/BaseTextureView( 3916): ******** GL Thread crash ********Thread[BaseTextureView-RenderThread,5,main]
W/System.err( 3916): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.nio.Buffer.capacity()' on a null object reference
W/System.err( 3916):    at com.here.android.mpa.internal.ae.d(GLBitmapDrawable.java:170)
W/System.err( 3916):    at com.here.android.mpa.internal.ae.a(GLBitmapDrawable.java:128)
W/System.err( 3916):    at com.here.android.mpa.internal.bf.a(MapMarkerImpl.java:216)
W/System.err( 3916):    at com.here.android.mpa.internal.ad.d(GLBitMapTileRenderer.java:682)
W/System.err( 3916):    at com.here.android.mpa.internal.ad.onDrawFrame(GLBitMapTileRenderer.java:1024)
W/System.err( 3916):    at com.here.android.mpa.internal.m$a.run(BaseTextureView.java:377)
E/BaseTextureView( 3916): ******** GL Thread crash ********Thread[BaseTextureView-RenderThread,5,main]
```

Comment: This is a bug in the SDK. Contact the here support team to have it fixed.

Comment: It will be fixed in the next Here SDK release.